# how do i make this script work on ios chrome

Tags: javascript, ios, google-chrome

Ok so the code below works on every browser except ios chrome and IE.
What changes can be made to make it compatible with those browsers

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  !function(){
    var campaign_link = "http://example.com/time&"; // REPLACE WITH YOUR LINK
    var t;             
    try{
      for(t=0;10>t;++t)history.pushState({},"","#");
      onpopstate=function(t){t.state&&location.replace(campaign_link)}}
    catch(o){}
  }();
</script>
```

Comment: Why is it not working. Do you have an error, wrong answer nothing at all?

Comment: this code is supposed to redirect any one who hits the back button. it works fine on all browsers except ios chrome and IE

Comment: so on ios chrome it does not redirect when the user hits a back button

Comment: You catch all the exceptions and discard them. Maybe one is thrown. Try to check if you have catched an exception.

Comment: Wait, you are pushing a bunch of link to your campaign to the history?! That's a sure way to make users angry (including me).

Comment: Yeah, that was my first thought @litelite.  Hijacking the back button to do something the user (most likely) doesn't want, can't be a good idea!

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error because of history API. Its not supported in sme browsers

All versions below Internet Explorer 9 definitely does not support  `history.pushState()` or `history.popState()`

iOS has a fair few bug with the HTML5 History API.

You can try like :

```
window.addEventListener("popstate", function(e) {
    window.location.href = location.href;
});
```

Comment: how would i  add it to the code i already have? Can you show me?